# Pointer on classelement and save the Pointer in a array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, save

this is my code:

```
    class Node {

private:
    unsigned number;
    unsigned color;


public:
    Knoten(unsigned int number = 0, unsigned int color = 0)
    {}

void set_number(unsigned int a){
    number = a;
}
void set_color(unsigned int b){
    color = b;
}

unsigned int get_number(void){
    return number;
}

unsigned int get_color(void){
    return color;
}
void print(void){
    cout << number << " " << color << endl;
    }
};

int main(){

Node node1, node 2, node 3;
Knoten* n1,n2,n3;
n1=&node1;
n2=&node1;
n3=&node1;

node1.set_number(1);
node1.set_color(3);

node2.set_number(2);
node2.set_color(5);

node3.set_number(3);
node3.set_color(7);

node1.ausgabe();
node2.ausgabe();
node3.ausgabe();

Node* matrix[2][2];

return 0;
```

Ok, i want to save the pointer in the array.
Once they are in the array, how do I edit the properties of each Array elements.
For Example.
n1 is save in matrix[0][0].
and the color is change from 3 to 10.
How i do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have correctly understood you and if do not take into account your invalid code then you can use expression

```
matrix[0][0]->set_color( 10 );
```

Or

```
if ( matrix[0][0]->get_color() == 3 ) matrix[0][0]->set_color( 10 );
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the simple. I tried a lot of things, but this idea did not come to me :D